# Get nested attributes associated with a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to write one of the test case where i am looking for a cleaner way of fetching nested attributes associated with the model

For eg

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

accepts_nested_attributes_for :devices, :books

#other association and code is not written here

end
```

**I expect**

```
$ Category.get_nested_attributes #this is a dummy method
$ ["devices","books"] #this is the return i expect
```

Is there any already existing helper method? If yes please let me know. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the rails source code (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L269), this code should work:

```
1.9.3p327 :002 > User.nested_attributes_options.keys
 => [:subscriptions]
```